# How to get a list of files opened and closed by a program execution?

Tags: c++, c, file, logging

I have the source code of a program. The source code is extremely huge and written in C/C++. I have the credentials to modify the source code, compile and execute it.

I want to know the filenames of all the files opened and closed by this program when it executes. It would be a plus if this list is sorted in the order the file operations occurred.

How can I get this information? Is there some monitoring tool I need to use or can I inject a library call into the C++ code to achieve this? The code is too large and complicated to hunt down every file open/close call and add a printf there. Or adding a pseudo macro to the file open API call might also be difficult.

Note that this is not the same as viewing what files are open currently by a process. I am aware of the many questions on StackOverflow that already address this problem (using lsof or /proc and so on).

Comment: Is it in C or in C++ ? What kind of program is it? How big is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strace` as below

```
$ strace -e trace=open,close -o /tmp/trace.log <your_program> <program_options>
```

In file `/tmp/trace.log` you will get all open, close operation done by the program.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to strace, you can use [interposition](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Applications_Debugging_Techniques/The_interposition_library) to intercept open/close syscalls. If you Google for "interposition shared library linux" you'll get many other references also.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding that you want to determine *statically* what files a given *source code* could open (for many runs of its compiled program).

If you just want to know it dynamically for a given run, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) as answered by [Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229410/rohan) and/or [interposition](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Applications_Debugging_Techniques/The_interposition_library) library as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486420/841108) by [Kec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521733/kec). Notice that [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) could also be useful, and perhaps more relevant (since you would trace `stdio`  or C++ library calls).

---

First, a program can (and many do) open a file whose name is some input (or some program argument). Then you cannot add that arbitrary file name to a list.

You could `#define fopen` and `#define open` to print a message. You could use `LD_PRELOAD` tricks to override `open`, `fopen`

If in C++, the program may open files using [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) etc...

You could consider customizing the GCC compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to help you...

Comment: ltrace seems like a very interesting tool. Thanks! :)